# RHEL6 Install MySql-Python without internet connection?

Tags: rhel, yum, python

Using RHEL 6 how can you install MySql-Python package without a internet connection?

I can SCP files to the server but our current restrictions do not allow a direct or proxy connection to the internet from the RHEL server. 
It looks like it can be easily installed via YUM however YUM cannot update repositories without an internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a similarly configured system I'd use [yumdownloader](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader). You can use it to download RPMs and their dependencies from yum repositories.

Something like this:

```
$ yumdownloader --resolve --destdir /tmp mysql-python
```

Once done downloading you can `scp` the *.rpm files to the other server.